# In Laravel Eloquent, select "whereIn" from parent table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

In my Laravel project (with MySQL database), I have a few models: **Time Entries**, **Tasks**, and **Projects**.

**Time Entries** belong to **Tasks**

**Tasks** belong to **Projects**

so each table contains a column for the corresponding ID of its parent.

I have an array of **Project** IDs, and I am trying to select the **time entries** which, through their **tasks**, belong to those projects.

In other words, I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
$timeEntries = TimeEntry::whereIn('project_id',$projectIds)->get();
```

But obviously, I get a column not found error, because all I've got in the **time entries** table is **task_id** rather than **project_id**.

Is there a way to select the desired time entries (based on the project IDs I have) in a single Eloquent query?  Help much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Add the following method in your Project model

```
public function timeEntries()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\TimeEntry' , 'App\Task');
}
```

now you can get all time entries of a project like below

```
$project = Project::find(id);
$project->timeEntries()->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

So the type of relation you're explaining is a *through* relation (http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through).

Instead of trying to head up the tree head down the tree from projects->tasks->time_entries.

```
Projects::whereIn($projectIds)->with('time_entries')->get();
```

The resulting collection will be projects with (should be at least) a field called time_entries in each project that have all the relevant times.